# MongoDB query not returning document when using $in

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in my collection and one of its properties can have a value of `null`, but for some reason, in that case, that document is never returned.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here -- the query works if the value is not null.

Here is what I have, [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wD0bYMUNRB8)

Comment: you have only one document in your $or array, with an implicit $and ($in... and read:false)

Comment: check this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/-NxJ26XvFOf